# Azure App Registration doesn't not allow wildcard BundleID

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create Azure App registration for my mobile App. I am trying to put com.companyname.* but it doesn't accept * wildcard character. I am trying to create 1 app registration for our multiple apps.

[image]

Is there a way use the wildcard for Bundle ID?

Comment: You can use one app registration by adding multiple bundle Ids, but each bundle ID must be explicit. You cannot use a wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide an explicit bundle ID.  You cannot use a wildcard.

After adding the first app to the Azure App registration you can then add more, one for each bundle ID.

You may want to consider whether this is the best approach though; The Azure Application defines a set of scopes/permissions that the app can request.  Using a single application for all of your apps limits your ability to manage these scopes.

There is no cost associated with creating an Azure AD App registration